# How to receive http response from action ngxs

Tags: angular, ngxs

How can I receive http response in component where I dispatch the action. I don't want to store result in the component. I only want to use http response in the component.

```
@Action(GetNovels, { cancelUncompleted: true })
  getNovels(ctx: StateContext<Novel[]>) {
    return this.novelsService.getNovels().pipe(
      tap(novels => {
        ctx.setState(novels);
      })
    );
  }
```

I tried to use life cycle hooks like `ofActionSuccess` but it is only returns the action I dispatched..

I look at the document but couldn't find any particular information about the subject.

Answer (score 1):

No idea why https://stackoverflow.com/a/74701490/628532 had -1, it should be the accepted answer.

Let me add more information:

NGXS respect **CQRS** pattern. **C** (*Command*) is your Action, **Q** (*Query*) is Selector and **RS** (*Responsibility Segregation*) means simply that you dont mix these two. You can imagine `Store` as your mediator and `Actions` class† as notification stream.

†: There I mean just and only `@ngxs/store/Actions` - not your `xxxAction` nor `@Action(xxxAction)`

This means that you really dont want any data back from dispatching action (**C** in CQRS), you want them thru Observable emitting changes in State (**Q** in CQRS). This is the main point of **RS**.

This also mean, you dont store your data in your component - you have only Observable emitting (somehow projected, if you wish) data. Your data are stored in state and you are making "queries" with your selectors. State is (well, should be ) immutable - you modify your state only thru actions (commands) and you only look at them through selectors (queries).

---

Back to code:

You can return `Observable` / `Promise` from your `@Action` and NGXS will subscribe to it. Great way to use this feature is dispatching another action inside `tap()` operator, like this:

```
// this is trivial example, so selectors would be trivial too. Sorry for that.
@Selector() public allNovels(state: Novel[]) { return state; }

// lets do something more real-life. Deduped all authors
// I am chaining selectors here. Result of prev selector is input of this one.
@Selector([NovelState.allNovels]) public allAuthors(novels: Novel[]) {
  // bcs selectors are memoized, this function will be called only
  // once for new data from allNovels and result will be "distributed"
  // to everyone interested.
  const r = [];
  novels
    .map(novel => novel.author)
    .forEach(author => {
      if(r.includes(author) === false)
      {
        r.push(author);
      }
    })
    .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
  
  return r;
}

// your original action.
// Because we return observable and we know it will be async (web request),
// we use { cancelUncompleted: true } for cases, when someone 
// dispatch GetNovels before previous returns.
@Action(GetNovels, { cancelUncompleted: true })
public getNovels(ctx: StateContext<Novel[]>) {
  return this.novelsService.getNovels().pipe(
    tap({
      next: (novelsFromServer) => {
        // there we dispatch GetNovelsComplete action with novels as payload
        ctx.dispatch(new GetNovelsComplete(novelsFromServer));
      },
      // same here, in case of error, we dispatch GetNovelsError action
      error: (err: unknown) => ctx.dispatch(new GetNovelsError(err)),
    }),
  );
}

@Action(GetNovelsComplete)
public getNovelsComplete(ctx: StateContext<Novel[]>, action: GetNovelsComplete) {
  ctx.setState(action.payload);
}

@Action(GetNovelsError)
public getNovelsComplete(ctx: StateContext<Novel[]>, action: GetNovelsError) {
  ctx.setState([]);
  this._tellUserSomethingWentWrongService.notify('Something went wrong while requesting Novels. Sry.', action.e);
}
```

This aproach have another benefit: It will work great with *Redux dev tools* browser extension - you will see "action GetNovels dispatched" and "action GetNovelsComplete dispatched" or "action GetNovelsError dispatched" with payloads, diff between previous and current state and many more information.

Then, you have to decide if your action should be handled.

You can go with selectors (99% of cases - mainly in Components) or some HandlerService (1% of cases - they work mainly as Notifications stream observers).

In components:

```
public readonly authors$; // TS will derive the correct type just fine.
constructor(private _store: Store) {
  this.authors$ = _store.select(NovelService.allAuthors);
}
```

Or you can use `@Select()`, but then you have to keep type "by hand" and you will get your Observable instances inside `OnInit()`

```
@Select(NovelService.allAuthors) authors: Observable<string> | undefined;
OnInit() {
}
```

In HandlerService, you use that `action$: Actions` piped with `ofActionDispatched` (or, even better, `ofActionCompleted`).

```
// note that there isnt { providedIn: 'root'}
// bcs Angular will tree-shake this Handler as unused.
// There are other ways to prevent this.
@Injectable()
export class NovelCompletedHandler {
  constructor(private _actions$: Actions)
  {
    _actions$
      .pipe(ofActionCompleted(GetNovelsComplete))
      // this Handler is not lazily provided (= no OnDestroy)
      // so I dont care about unsubsribe
      .subscribe({
        next: (action) => { doSomething(); }
      });
  }
}
```

To be honest, in last month or two I wrote only two Handlers (One was manipulating `Title` and second was adding some attribute on `<body>`). `Actions` stream have its use, but you probably dont need them. Selectors are your bread and butter.

---

Another example:

What would you do, when your POST your novel to REST api and got back only id, which you need for another GET call?

For example, endpoint `POST /novels/` will return

```json
{ state: 'success', errors: null, id: 123 }
{ state: 'fail', errors: [{type: 'validation', message: 'Novel need authorId'}], id: null}
```

and endpoint `GET /novels/{:id}` will return actual novel...

(Lets ignore for a second that your NovelService can solve this by RXJS `mergeMap(postResponse => { if(postResponse.state === ...) {...} else {...}})` and lets look how you would solve this with NGXS)

This is actually really easy - you `pipe(tap())` another command dispatch in returned observable and you can do it again.

Its like continuation of command:

```
@Action(CreateNovel)
public createNovel(ctx: StateContext<Novel[]>, action: CreateNovel) {
  return this.novelsService
    .postNovel(action.payload)
    .pipe(
      // Doesnt really matter if I write "what to do next"
      // there in in pipe or i do whole action.
      tap({
        next: (serverResponse) => {
          if(serverResponse.state === ResponseStates.Success)
          {
            // ok, we have id - we can ask for real Novel
            ctx.dispatch(new LoadNovelById(serverResponse.id));
          } else if (serverResponse.state === ResponseState.Fail)
          {
            // in case of error, we dispatch GetNovelsError action
            ctx.dispatch(new GetNovelsError(serverResponse.errors)
          }
        },
        // in case of error, we dispatch GetNovelsError action
        error: (err: unknown) => ctx.dispatch(new GetNovelsError(err)),
      }),
  );
}

@Action(LoadNovelById)
public loadNovel(ctx: StateContext<Novel[]>, action: LoadNovelById)
{
  return this.novelsService
    .getById(action.payload)
    .pipe(
      tap({
        next: (novel) => ctx.dispatch(new LoadNovelComplete(novel));
        error: (er: unknown) => ctx.dispatch(new LoadNovelError(er));)
      })
    );
}

@Action(LoadNovelComplete)
public loadNovelComplete(ctx: StateContext<Novel[]>, action: LoadNovelComplete)
{
  // bcs our state is array, we can use append operator
  // https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/operators
  ctx.setState(append(action.payload));
}

@Action(LoadNovelError)
public loadNovelError(ctx: StateContext<Novel[]>, action: LoadNovelError) {
  const payload = action.payload;
  // we log the error to console
  console.error(LoadNovelError.type, payload);
  // and we send it to our notificationService
  if (payload instanceof HttpErrorResponse || payload instanceof Error) {
    this._notificationService.error(payload.message);
  } else if (typeof payload === 'string') {
    this._notificationService.error(payload);
  }
  // etc...
}
```

And thats it.

Comment: This question was discussed on [ngxs slack](https://join.slack.com/t/ngxs/shared_invite/zt-by26i24h-2CC5~vqwNCiZa~RRibh60Q). That's why the answer is so long

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to select the state after your action is completed.

E.g. in your component something like this:

```
this.store.dispatch(new GetNovels())
.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(this.store.select(NovelsState)),
  tap(([_, novelsState]) => {
     // do something with the 'response' which is now captured in the new state
  }),
).subscribe();
```

As you mentioned you could also use the action lifecycle hooks if you want to do something post-action but you didn't dispatch the action - again you could also grab the current state using `withLatestFrom` in that case.

This usage is touched on in the documentation for [dispatching actions](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/store#dispatching-actions).

Comment: This is fine for GET request but what about a POST where you want to get the newly created resource id?

Answer (score 0):

You can add new action - `GetNovelsComplete`:

```
@Action(GetNovels)
getNovels(ctx: StateContext<Novel[]>) {
  return this.novelsService.getNovels().pipe(
    tap(novels => {
      ctx.setState(novels);
      ctx.dispatch(new GetNovelsComplete(novels));
    }),
    catchError(error => {
      ctx.dispatch(new GetNovelsComplete([]));
      return throwError(() => error)
    }),
  );
}

@Action(GetNovelsComplete)
getNovelsComplete() {
}
```

then:

```
this.actions$.pipe(
  ofActionDispatched(GetNovelsComplete)
).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Why this got -1? Its great answer. You can return observable (NGXS will subsribe it for you) with `tap()` to another dispatch - the second one will contains results...